# Which dash to use in citations while writing "number"?

Tags: dashes, typography, citation

Consider the following citation:

> Dasgupta, P. (1992). Pronominality and deixis in Bangla. Linguistic analysis,
> *22*(1–2).

This represents 22nd volume of the concerned journal and 1–2 number. I am wondering which dash would be more appropriate here?

Comment: What does the journal's style guide say you should use?

Comment: @KillingTime this is a part of my PhD coursework submission and my department doesn't have any prescriptive rule for this. They will accept any. I only want to adhere to some standard. I am okay with the existence of other standards, but I want to adhere to one particular system consistently and with a conscious understanding.

Comment: I don't know if this will be relevant, but I tend to follow British conventions of English. So I would appreciate suggestions which don't violate them.

Comment: What does the (1—2) represent? Is it a range of pages (e.g. pages 1 to 2) or a section and paragraph number (e.g. section 1 paragraph 2) or something else?

Comment: @KillingTime I think it specifies issues of the volume, so not a range, independent numbers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think it does. I am still not very sure if it is a range as I have said in my earlier comment. They look like independent numbers. E.g., The story spanned from pp. 1–2 looks very different from the 1–2 of the citation written in the question.

Comment: But how does the answer you accept here differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style notes:

> The principal use of the en dash is to connect continuing, or inclusive, numbers—dates, time, or reference numbers. (CMOS 14th ed., secton 5.115)

It gives some examples of en dashes in source citations, but they are all used for ranges of years or page numbers. Presumably en dashes would also be used for ranges of issue numbers. (I took a quick look through some books and journals I have at home and found plenty of ranges of page numbers with en dashes but couldn't find any ranges of issue numbers; perhaps someone else can find an example.)

Keep in mind that you could avoid the issue entirely by simply using a comma to join the two numbers. However, if you have wider ranges elsewhere, than an en dash would clearly work better.

Comment: Oh the last advice makes so much sense!! I clearly don't have an engineer's mind hehe. Also thanks for the other efforts. It clears a lot of my doubts.

Comment: I think numbering an issue 11-12 or similar is sometimes done if for some reason they are unable to bring out an edition and combine it with the next, to keep numbering consistent, incrementing by the same amount each year (e.g. if it's a quarterly, they still have 4 numbers per year even if there are only 3 editions actually published).

Comment: @StuartF Yes, that's true. It's not entirely clear whether OP's example cites a "double issue" or two distinct issues, though an en dash could work in either case, as you say.